# How to give html button tag an image

Tags: html, button

I am wondering if there is a way to give the HTML button tag, `<button>` an image so the image is click-able on my webpage. That way when users click on the image I can have other things happen

This doesn't seem to be working, and was wondering if it is even possible

HTML code -

```
<button>
<img src="images/dagger.png" width="10%" height="10%" id="dagger" />
</button>
```

Comment: You should use <div> and bind events in other way.

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you remove width and height? I'd say that this should work, but width & height at 10% might give you an _extremely_ tiny image.

Comment: old post - but what he has does work

Answer (score 19):

Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VRvUB/) example helps.

HTML

```
<button>
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_32.png" id="dagger" />
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $("#dagger").click(function(){
        alert("click");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You could set the image as button background

```
button {
    background-image:url('images/dagger.png');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issues, and thought I would drop this post for anyone in the future that sees this thread.

From my understanding, you're not wanting a BUTTON, but a clickable image that acts as a button. Here is what I did:

HTML:

```
<img src="images/dagger.png" width="10%" height="10%" id="dagger" />
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
 $("#dagger").click(function(){
     // what you wanted your button to do when user clicks it    
 });
</script>
```

By doing it this way, you get rid of the normal "button" image, and you can use whatever image you want as your clickable button. As well, you get the same functionality that you're wanting from the button, and it opens up many other paths to achieving your purposes.

Hope it helps!

---

Another method I use is simply putting the `onclick` event on the `img` itself to call a function.

html:

```
<img src="images/dagger.png" width="10%" height="10%" id="dagger" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

JS:

```
<script>
 myFunction() {
   // what I want to happen if user clicks image
 }
</script>
```

Depending upon what you're doing, and what you're trying to manipulate, all of the examples on this page will provide you with better/worse ways of doing it. Using the `onclick` event within the `img` tag, you can pass variables/information to the function to utilize, and then have the function relay it to your PHP/ASP/etc.. As well, if you were dealing with a form, you can have your function handle information/submission, rather than the default submission that forms use. Use your imagination with the problems you come across, and decide which method works out better. Never settle for learning just one way of doing something.

Comment: img tag would not get keyboard focus

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't use a button you can just bind the click event to the image with JavaScript.

But if you must have a button you can style the button using CSS and the background-image property.

Comment: Forcing a simple form button to require JS for aesthetic purposes is less than desireable.

Comment: img tag also would not get keyboard focus