# How to make a button value invisible and add an image to the button

Tags: css, html

How can I assign an image to the button and make it's value disappear so that only the image appears on the screen. I am working with PHP and HTML5.

The following code works, the image appears but along with the image the value of the button is also displayed on the screen. I cannot remove the value attribute because I need it to find  an ID of the item displayed.

PHP CODE (Inserting a td into a dynamic table)

```
<?php $url = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/deleteButton1.png'; ?>
<td class='delete'><button id="gm_btn_delete_order_prod"  value="{$product_id}"     class="button"></button></td>
```

CSS

```
.button
        {
        background: url(<?php echo $url; ?>) no-repeat;
        cursor:pointer;
                    border: none;
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818543/how-to-give-html5-button-tag-an-image  Did you look at this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS to move the text to a position off the page like:

```
.button {
   text-indent: -10000px;
}
```

From Terry's comment, could do something like:

```
.button {
   text-indent: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Or, use the new text-indent replacement, mainly because a highly negative text-indent actually forces the browser to render all the pixels specified ;) http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/

Comment: @fanfavorite, Thanks for the answer, I tried it and it worked well. Is there any other way to make the text invisible? If not then this is the only option I have to add text indent into my css.

Comment: @Terry:  by text indent replacement did you mean the following code in css?
.hide-text {
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: @Terry didn't realize this. I have added your solution as well.

Comment: @user2149838 don't think its possible at this time.

Comment: I just came across another problem. When I tried the above CSS I get a space and then a letter T. Clicking on the letter make it shift towards the right side.

Comment: @fanfavorite You're welcome. I was also recently introduced this new trick, and I think it's a wee bit more elegant ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could use a data-value attribute on the button to store your needed value then pull it out with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a link instead buttons and pass the parameters via `GET` or with javascript `POST/PUT`
Use this tutorial to make pretty image buttons with links or just buttons/input submit http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

**update**
I'am working now, on a website that has a button that is a image, the code:

**css**

```
input[type="submit"] {
position: absolute;
width: 122px;
height: 33px;
margin: 382px 0 0 500px;
border: 0 none;
background: none;
background-image: url(/images/asset/form.png);
background-position: -678px -525px;
z-index: 2;
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="submit" value="">
```

Comment: Hey Lucas,
I dont want text as I'm just trying to put a cross button(picture)

Comment: With that you don't need to put text on the link, the code finish something like `<a href='yourlink.php?id=34' class='btn'></a>` and the css file put the image and fix the width/height of the element. The bootstrap framework use a lot of links button like and behavior.