# Placing button over full width & height image in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, button

I'm currently having trouble with placing button over image in Wordpress. Since I have Visual Composer  plugin installed on my website, I tried different solutions but all of them ended with failure.

My goal is to place a button over an image which will be full width and full height. I recently tried creating a row, making my image as the row's background image and placing button over it. But in that case the image is either stretched or small. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking for. If you want to just place a button over an image, without hiding the button try the following from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp):

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow">
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

If that isn't what you want, and you want to convert your image to a button try the following I found in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818543/how-to-give-html-button-tag-an-image):

HTML

```
<button>
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_32.png" id="dagger" />
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $("#dagger").click(function(){
        alert("A popup!");
    }); 
});
```

NOTE: If that didn't work for you, check out the StackOverflow link. There are a few other ideas.